# Create a private JS module that's shared between server and client

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

My server is NodeJs with Firebase and client is React. I would like to create a local shared module between server and client. So I created this common folder, outside of server directory. This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Data structure shared between server and client",
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true
}
```

Then I did a "npm install -S ../common" as tutorial instructed. It modified server's package.json and created a link in node_modules. Seems OK. However when I tried to deploy it to server, I got this error:

```
Deployment error.
Build failed: exit status 254
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /common
```

Is it even possible to do such a thing?

Comment: How your server package.json looks like after that you installed `common` module?

Comment: 'common':"file:../common",